# How to identify an appliance connector

Tags: repair, appliances, connectors

I have a dishwasher that has a corroded connector on the wire harness (part number [W10195342](http://www.kitchenaid.com/digitalassets/MLPDF/Repair%20Part%20List%20-%20W10370678.pdf#page=6)) connecting to the motor and diverter valve (part number [W10056349](http://www.kitchenaid.com/digitalassets/MLPDF/Repair%20Part%20List%20-%20W10370678.pdf#page=12)). Only the one connector on the harness needs replacing. My guess is that it's a standard connector available from Digi-Key or the like, but with what seems like zillions of connectors to choose from, how do I identify which one?

Is there some kind of connector taxonomy or part identification tree? Some way to determine the name and/or part number of the specific connector?

[image: Connector]

Comment: Use the brand and model# and Google for the parts list I have been able to find every part for most appliances. Right down to the fasteners.

Comment: @EdBeal The dishwasher is a KitchenAid KUDE60FXPA1. The relevant part numbers are in the question. I've Googled everything I could think of, but haven't found the connector. If you can find it, I'd appreciate knowing the part identification and the technique you used to find it.

Comment: I googled "motor wire harness KitchenAid Dishwasher KUDE60FXPA1 " and the complete wire harness was 97$ there may be one to the motor only but on my phone I could not see the parts clear enough to tell of the less expensive part was just to the correct motor or a different one. The other one was under 20$ , 2nd site I looked a a bit cheaper but same pics I can't make out on my phone

Answer (score 1):

In general, connectors like that are classified based on the pin thickness and pin spacing.  That might cut your solution set from a million connector models down to a few hundred thousand: useful but hardly solving the issue.

Posting photos of the far side of this connector would help also. Major vendors love to make one off connector designs so nothing else will fit.  In which case you're out of luck, short of finding a used connector harness, or scavenging similar models at a dump. Sometimes you can get lucky and the only difference is a keying pin (like the plastic bumps at the top of your photo).  Then you just cut off the keying feature and run with it.

If it were my washer, I'd probably saw open the failed connector, solder the wires directly to the pins, gently insert bare pins into the valve, and seal it all up with an appropriate clear silicon caulk (clear so I can see if anything goes wrong).

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to first mark the wires then cut the connector off completely.  Now make quality individual splices of the wires.

Comment: I updated the question to indicate that the corroded connector connects to the motor and diverter valve. There doesn't seem to be a good way to splice directly into that part.